# can you have a text value display based on what integer it is?

Tags: php

i have a table that is displaying the value from an integer field. so the app works like this:
the user selects an option from the radio selection, each value is an integer, so 1 is math, 2 is english and 3 is spanish. However in my table field, it just shows the number when displaying the table in a view, how can i make it such that 1 in the db table shows math on the view?

heres my table code:

```
@foreach ( $subject as $code)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$code->subjectType}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you have a table that contains the dropdown values and texts?

Comment: no i dont, just radios

Comment: Then you probably should, how else will you do this if you dont. Before you try hard coding a bunch of IF's that will be a maintenance problem in the future

Comment: Well you can use an associative array in Php to store the codes and the corresponding 
subject names

Comment: @NadirLatif how would i do that?

Comment: `if ($code->subjectType == 1) echo "Math" elseif ($code->subjectType == 2) echo "English" else echo "Spanish"`

Comment: For example `$arr = array(1 => "Math", 2 => "English);`

Comment: @NadirLatif but how with this work in a <td> tag>

Comment: The following should work: `<td>{{$arr[$code->subjectType]}}</td>`. It seems like you are using a template library for displaying the table. If so then you need to declare the array of codes and subjects outside the template and then use it within the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$subjectCodes = [1=>'Math', 2=>'English', 3=>'Spanish'];
?>
@foreach ( $subject as $code)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$subjectCodes[$code->subjectType]}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```